Let $X$ have a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, 1)$. Find the pdf of $Y=X(1-X)$
From the uniform distribution, I know that the pdf and CDF of $X$ are, respectively:
$
f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 
          1, & 0 < x < 1 \\
          0, & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases}
$
$
F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0, & x\leq 0 \\
          x, & 0 < x < 1 \\
          1, & x \geq 1
       \end{cases}
$
I also know that the CDF of $Y$ is given by $ F_Y(y) = P [\ Y \le y ]\ = P [\ X(1-X) \le y ]\ $. From here, I would like to leave the event in terms of $X$, so I can use the CDF of $X$ which is known, to then differentiate and find the pdf of $Y$, but I can't solve it.
I am asked to do it this way, not using "transformation methods".
How should I proceed here?
Thanks.

Do you know how to solve a quadratic inequality like $x^2+x+2\leq0$?

Well, I know how to solve $x-x^2-y \leq 0$. It gives two interval solutions, but I still don't know how to use it. Also, I found that $x-x^2$ is never negative, since $x \in (0,1)$, then for $y \leq 0$ the CDF is $0$. And also, since all the values of $x-x^2$ belong to (0,1), then for $y \geq 1$ the CDF would be 1. But what happens when $0 < y < 1$?.

Edit your question and include all of this, and the interval solutions. Otherwise this question, as of now, doesn't meet the site standards and might attract downvotes. Only after you edit, people will start answering this question.

First notice that $P(0\leq X(1-X)\leq \frac{1}{4})=1$.
Now note that for $y\in [0,\frac{1}{4}]$, $x(1-x)\leq \frac{1}{4}$ if $0\leq x\leq\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y}}{2}$ or if $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4y}}{2}<x<1$
Now \begin{align}P(Y\leq y)&=P(0\leq X\leq \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y}}{2})+P(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4y}}{2}\leq X\leq 1)\\\\&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y}}{2}+1-\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4y}}{2}\bigg)\\\\&=1-\sqrt{1-4y}\end{align}
So the CDF of $Y$ is given by :-
$F_{Y}(y)=\begin{cases}0\,, y\leq 0\\ 1-\sqrt{1-4y}\,,0<y<\frac{1}{4}\\1\,,y\geq \frac{1}{4}\end{cases}$
Now you can differentiate wrt $y$ to find the PDF.
